# how to get height and width of multiple image with same id using java script

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get width and height of multiple images which have same id. I am doing drag & drop a rectangular image into canvas. For the first image I can get the height and width. When I drag & drop the second rectangle image I couldn't get the new image's width and height. It shows the old image value in the console. But in the screen its height and width varies. I need both values.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<li><span id="drag1" class="drag"><img id="vino" src="images/rect-1.png" onmouseout="bigImg(this)" width="100%" height="100%" /></span><span>Item 1</span> </li>

<!--script-->
   function bigImg(x) {
   var img = document.getElementById('vino'); 
   var width = img.clientWidth;
   var height = img.clientHeight;
   console.log("function called");
   console.log(width);
   console.log(height);
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Multiple images cannot have same id. The concept of ID is to uniquely identify an element. Use same class to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

DOM elements should have unique IDs, what you should do is to have a common class name for these elements.

`<li class="dragMe" ....></li>`

and then, your selector should return an array of elements if more than one element is found, iterate through that array of DOM elements and get the properties you wish like width and height.

```
$('.dragMe').each(function(){
  var height = $(this).height();
  var outerHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
  var innerHeight = $(this).innerHeight();
  ...... 
});
```

Update: if you want to get the current elements height and width of the dropped image. Then using jQuery UI D&D, the DOM element with class name `drop` is the element that will receive your dragged pictures.

```
$(".drop").droppable({ accept: ".block", 
  drop: function(ev, ui) { 
     console.log(ui.draggable);         
  }
});
```

the `ui.draggable` is the element dropped, you get its properties then